# how to construct and sample from conditional multi-variate normal distribution?

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

The two random variables $D$ and $W$ represent the uncertainty of average price of a product in the daily (short resolution) and weekly (long resolution) time-interval .  On the other hand, the variation of the average price of the product over a longer period (week) is lower than a shorter (daily) period. Moreover, it is assumed that the both random variables (weekly and daily average price) follow a normal distribution. I want a probability distribution function (perhaps multi-variate and/or conditional) to represent the uncertainty around these two variables (Q1). Secondly, I want to draw $K$ samples from this distribution function (Q2).

Let's say $w_1, ..., w_N$ represents the uncertainty around the weekly average price with a mean of $\overline{w}$ and a standard deviation of $\sigma_w$. For each weekly sample, $w_i$, the daily average price samples should have a mean equal to the corresponding weekly sample and the standard deviation as a function of the corresponding weekly price (or even constant). That is $D_{wi}^{dj},\ j=1:M$ are M daily average price sample corresponding the sample $w_i$. The mean of $D_{wi}^{dj},\ j=1:M$ is equal to $w_i$ and its STD, $\sigma_d =w_i/10$.

For example, `N=2` samples regarding the average oil price during a week with the mean of $\overline{w} = 100 $ and $\sigma_{w} = 20 $ are as follows.

${w_1} = 80, {w_2} = 120 $ `% Two samples drawn from N(100,20)`

Also, for each weekly sample, we have `M=3` samples characterizing the daily variation of the price with $D_{wi}^{dj=1:M} = w_i$ and  $ \sigma_{d} = 30$ (Considered to be independent of the weekly samples for the sake of simplicity in this example).

$D_{w1}^{d1}= 50, D_{w1}^{d2} = 80, D_{w1}^{d3} = 110 \quad \text{ Drawn from N($w_1$ = 80,$ \sigma_{d} = 30$)}\\
D_{w2}^{d1}= 90, D_{w2}^{d2} = 120, D_{w2}^{d3} = 150 \quad \text{ Drawn from N($w_2$=120,$ \sigma_{d} = 30$)}$

How can I address Q1 and Q2 (finding the probability distribution function and sampling from it) for the given problem?

Comment: I don't see how this question could possibly be answered, because it doesn't explain how $D$ and $W$ are known or in what form they are given.  It only describes some data.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: It is assumed that both variables follow normal distribution. Also, the question is modified and an illustrative example with respect to the expectation of the question is given.  @whuber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sampling (Q2), one approach would be to use a two-stage sampling procedure.

1. Assuming that weekly average prices follows a $N(\mu_\omega, \sigma_\omega)$ it is straightforward to sample $N$ realizations using a random number generator
2. For *each* realization $i=1,..,N$, the daily average prices follows a $N(\omega_i,\sigma_d)$. If you sample $N$ realizations for each $\omega_i$ you will get a scenario tree with $N^2$ leaves

But since $W$ is a temporal aggregation of $D$, you could work directly with the latter. You can sample daily average prices from a Normal Distribution and then estimate weekly averages.

Comment: Yes this could work, but if you apply scenario reduction you should do it after having sampled both stages. However, sampling only average daily prices and creating weekly will probably be just fine and it's simpler.